# Spring Integration WS Outbound Gateway POC - XMLMarshalException

Tags: xml, spring, web-services, jaxb, spring-integration

I am developing a POC on Spring Integration with following usecase.

- Subscribing input message (A) from remote JMS Queue
- Transforming input message (A) to (B)
- Invoking a remote Webservice with (B) and receiving the response

my spring-int config xml has following

---

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="marshallingGateway" request-channel="mdmIntInputChannel" reply-channel="mdmIntOutputChannel" 
        uri="ws-endpoint" marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"/>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.veeaar.ws.types.jaxb"/>
```

---

Have all my jaxb generated source in my spring integration proj workspace.

While executing this in STS 3.8.3, the following error is being thrown.

Not sure what is wrong in my code. Any help resolving this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class java.lang.String was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:908)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:684)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway$MarshallingRequestMessageCallback.doWithMessageInternal(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway$RequestMessageCallback.doWithMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:233)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:590)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:87)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ... 36 more
```

Am explaining further my POC here to understand more why JAXB conversion needed before invoking the remote webservice.

The XSL transformation I doing in Spring Integ converts from input message of "Event" to "fetchCodeByName" message as given below.

```
<tns:fetchCodeByName xmlns:tns="http://www.veeaar.com/remote/wsdl/2010-1" xmlns:ns1="http://www.veeaar.com/remote/xml/2010-1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<ns1:Code>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
</ns1:Code>
</tns:fetchCodeByName>
```

In WSDL, fetchCodeByName is mapped to CodesType of ns1 namespace. Have generated JAXB classes from 'Codes' schema XSD.

Before invoking the remote web service, if I create a service activator and try to unmarshall the transformation output to JAXB object, we get error reporting as unmarshalling task expecting 'Codes' as root element not 'fetchCodeByName'.

How to resolve this issue?

Is there any way in Spring Integration, can we invoke a remote web service without marshall and unmarshal the input message? Can't we just direct the XSLT output straightway to int-ws:outbound-gateway?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, consider to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question isn't readable without proper formatting. Too hard to help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for inputs. Have formatted the question and hope its readable now.

Comment: Good. I see now. So, the question is: doesn't that exception say that your `payload` for the `mdmIntInputChannel` is a String instead of some JaxB mapped POJO ?

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for pointing out. I am still not clear how to proceed. I have updated my original post with more info on what errors I now get after trying to convert the webservice input to JAXB mapping XML message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to unmarshal before WS Outbound Gateway? You see, you then marshal it again! Just use `simple` WS Outbound Gateway variant (without `marshaller`) and send an XSLT transformer result in its `input` channel as is.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for inputs. It worked after I removed marshaller task. Am able to send XSLT transformer result directly to WS outbound Gateway and receive the response back from remote webservice.

Comment: Can you please tell me which usecases require marshaller and unmarshaller tasks in Spring Integration when we deal with various adapters? Thanks.

Comment: When you build a POJO based on the JaxB annotations and it is represented as a `payload` for that WS Gateway. As well as you are expecting POJO as a result from the gateway. Since you build XML manually (even over XSLT), there is no reason to worry about POJO layer.